# present tense or present participle?

Tags: present-participles

I created the following sentences:

> 1. Measure the speed of the uncoiled spring **returning** to its original
>      length.
> 2. Measure the speed at which the uncoiled spring **returns(is returning)** to
>      its original length.

I would like to know which is correct or sounds more natural. I usually make sentences such as the second one because I think it is easier for non-natives to understand.

Comment: springs, which are coils, are said to be coiled or uncoiled. We do not use the word stretch here. http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/determine-stiffness-k-torsional-spring-bars-released-rest-0-chapter-18-problem-67p-solution-9780133009569-exc

Comment: Both (1) and (2) are grammatical, and neither is more correct or natural than the other. The idea that, of two different ways to say the same thing, one must be better than the other (or, in the extreme case, only one is "correct") is false and should be avoided. There are **always** several correct ways to say something.

Comment: 'Stretch' is fine for the macroscopic distortion.  It is only atomic bonds (whether steel or rubber) that *bend* more than *stretch*.  (2) is a bit clearer, since a comma after 'spring' in (1) could change the meaning.